# Product images are not shown on front page on magento 1.8 e-commerce website

Tags: magento

can you please help to fix the issue of "Images not shown on front page".

I am new to Magento and I don't know internal code of Magento. I am using admin option. I am using Magento 1.8.1 (latest version) free theme "Womem fashion" and configured it using online documents. My domain is [b]mychoice4life.com[/b]

I have uploaded images and product details using import option. I spent 24 hours to fix the image  issue but no success. What I have done so far...

1. Created categories and added one product manually. I set image for the one product.
2. Exported product in csv format.
3. Added more products in the newly download csv. Added details in required fields. [product qty, dates, evverything]
4. Imported csv data into system and products were shown on front page without image. product image start with dn so I copied my images in /MyChoice4Life/magento/media/catalog/product/d/n/*.jpg. In csv file, I  set image path as /d/n/product1.jpg
5. I set media folder permission as 777 (all sub folders).
6. I cleared cache from cache management. (There are multiple buttons to clear different cache, i called on all buttons.)
7. I deleted all files from /var/cache folder.
8. Re-indexed products.
9. Cleared browser cache.
10. I tried IE,FF and chrome browsers.

Still product images are not shown. If I manually update product image from product page, image is getting displayed on front page and magento adds new image file in same folder by adding _1 in file name. i.e. if dnproduct.jpg exists in the ../d/n/ folder, new image will be added as dnproduct_1.jpg. This mean, I have uploaded images in correct folder.

When I edit product details on product page, image is not getting displayed in image tab in admin page. I need to re-upload image.
I am software engineer so I tried all possible way I know except changing code.  I need to upload 5000 products and don't want to upload images manually from admin page.

Other problem is, I modified few images which are shown at top  for this theme but those images are also not getting displayed.

I modifed 4 images at the folder   /MyChoice4Life/magento/media/wysiwyg/pagayo/pt002

Please guide me.  If you have solution, please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Bharat Patel

Comment: Did you tell magento to reindex and clear caches, etc... ?

Comment: Yes, I tried every possible way... Re-indexed, cleared cache,deteled few folders from /var/cache ...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion if you plan on importing into Magento is to use [Magmi, Magento Mass Importer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/).

It will take care of a lot of things that need to be setup in Magento for you.

I have used it with massive imports with images that had to be fetched remotely and it was very solid. Magmi supports remote and local image importing so you should be good.

Comment: Thanks Lagbox. Let me try it out.

Comment: Hi Lagbox, I copied magmi to my domain's root folder. Set permission 777 instead of 705 (just to try so that I do not get any error) I tried to access http://mychoice4life.com/magmi/web/ or http://mychoice4life.com/magmi/ but getting 403 error. You don't have permission to access /magmi/web/ on this server.  Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

ok ..try this..put your images in `media -> import folder.(You need to create the import folder).`

And just put `the image name in your CSV under image column.`